# Does a BinaryHeap use PartialEq for sort order only or for genuine equivalence?

Tags: rust

I want to store `MyStruct` in a `BinaryHeap` using my own ordering criteria. I have to implement `Ord` and `PartialEq`, but will the heap use the `PartialEq` only for ordering or will it also use it to decide that `MyStruct` instance 1 and `MyStruct` instance 2 are logically the same object and hence could jiggle things around behind my back?

For example, could it decide "well next up is `inst2` but I already have `inst1` here in some cache and so I will just return that again"?

My instances are very different objects - they just have the same sort key.

I have this code. Is it bad because my `Eq` implementation only compares the things I want to sort on? I want to put these objects in a `BinaryHeap`. In my current code I put them in a `Vec` and sort after each insert which is suboptimal.

```
type TQIFunc = fn() -> ();

struct TimerQueueItem {
    when: Instant, // when it should run
    name: String,  // for trace only
    what: TQIFunc, // what to run
}

impl Ord for TimerQueueItem {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &TimerQueueItem) -> Ordering {
        other.when.cmp(&self.when)
    }
}

// `PartialOrd` needs to be implemented as well.
impl PartialOrd for TimerQueueItem {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &TimerQueueItem) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for TimerQueueItem {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.when == other.when
    }
}

impl Eq for TimerQueueItem {}
```

`TQI1` is equal to `TQI2` if they have the same `when` value - when in fact I just want to sort by the `when` value.

Will the `BinaryHeap` make other assumptions about two things being equal or is it just used for sorting? I agree that what the code does today is not a good thing to base the answer on; I am mainly concerned that `BinaryHeap` does not think that `TQI1` is a logical clone of `TQI2` because I assert that they are equal.

Comment: just implement a wrapper that handle your specific use, `struct Wrapper(MyRealStruct);`, so you can implement Ord that make sense for your wrapper without allow miss use of your real struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs for `BinaryHeap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html) state that it is: "*A priority queue implemented with a binary heap*". The whole point of a priority queue is that you can insert different items that have the same priority and get the same items back out. So in your case, you can have several items with the same `when` value and they will still be distinct items in the queue. You can also put the exact same item twice in the queue, and you will get it back as many times as you put it in.

The only thing you can't guarantee: if you insert several items that compare equal, then there is no guarantee on the order you get them back.

Comment: Well, that’s an interpretation of the doc. If I say that a and b are equal then I can imagine an implementation that returns a twice. For simple things this is a meaningless distinction, 42 === 42. But for complex types this is not so. The doc doesn’t even say if you can insert 42 twice. That is only based on ‘everybody knows what a priority queue is’

Comment: Except than in a priority queue, you don't say that a and b "are equal" but rather that they "have equal priority".

Comment: Except that binaryheap docs don’t mention eq/partialeq at all. Who knows what use bh makes of it? The only way tell is by looking at the implementation, but, as we know, that’s no guarantee

Answer (score -2):

Rust will only use the `Ord` trait for the `BinaryHeap` (and the `Ord` trait requires the `PartialEq` trait). You can see it [in the source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/alloc/src/collections/binary_heap.rs#L512-L526) where they sift up the heap:

```rust
fn sift_up(&mut self, start: usize, pos: usize) -> usize {
    unsafe {
        // Take out the value at `pos` and create a hole.
        let mut hole = Hole::new(&mut self.data, pos);

        while hole.pos() > start {
            let parent = (hole.pos() - 1) / 2;
            if hole.element() <= hole.get(parent) {
                break;
            }
            hole.move_to(parent);
        }
        hole.pos()
    }
}
```

The comparisons are done with `<=` which uses `Ord`.

Comment: ty  - why is this marked unsafe - which bit needs it?

Comment: This might be how `BinaryHeap` is implemented today, but it could be different tomorrow. The only guarantees you should be relying on for correct behavior are the ones that are documented in the API.

Comment: What @trentcl posits isn't even an outrageous suggestion — Rust's `HashMap` has already been completely rewritten once.

Comment: @trentcl - the docs for BinaryHeap dont say anyhting about Eq, only that I must implement PartialOrd, which requires Eq. But I agree that just because it works like that today is no guarantee. However I bet there is a lot of code that stores structs in binaryheaps that assume implicity that Eq doesnt mean anything stronger